# Javascript counter issue

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm studying javascript basics. 
I'm trying to make a little program to count number from 1 to 100 using a for cycle.

I wrote this, and it's okay, I got numbers till 99.

```
for ( i = 0; i <= 99; i++ ) {
  i++;
  console.log(i);
}
```

But if I try this, I got 101, why?

```
for ( i = 0; i <= 100; i++ ) {
  i++;
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Um, why are you incrementing `i` twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're performing `i++` twice per each loop. Once inside the for loop declaration, once inside the for loop block. Remove i++ from the loop block, and you'll have it.

Edit: you will also need to start the loop at `1` by setting `(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)`

Comment: Thank you, stupid mistake, but are my first steps with js. Why people are downvoting this question ?

Comment: @IvanPalma Because if you had checked the code twice before posting you would have caught it yourself.

Comment: @Dan -- If the increment inside the loop is removed, then the loop will start printing from 0, not 1.

Comment: Perhaps I had understood that I had to use ++ to increase a number. Sorry, didn't born a developer like you all.

Comment: @IvanPalma: You *do* use `++` to increase a number (although it isn't the only way).  The problem was that you were doing it in 2 different places.  If you had looked more closely at your output, you would have seen that only odd numbers were being "printed".

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @Dan's answer:  Because your program incremented `i` twice in each iteration, it was only printing out odd numbers.  Eventually, `i` got to 98, and in both cases stayed in the loop, incremented it again to 99, and "printed" it.  This got incremented to 100 before testing to end the loop; the first code saw this was greater than 99, so stopped, but the second code saw it wasn't greater than 100, so incremented it and printed it, but stopped the next time around (when it got bumped up to 102).